# Extract content from RSS and display or save it as a new file

Tags: php, rss

I would like to know if there is any way to get a RSS from a page that interests me, remove all google ads from it and save the result (title, post and image or image url) to a text or html file.

Maybe PHP would make the magic, I do not know...
Any clues about my question are welcome!

Comment: Scroll fast then blink when ads appearing.

Comment: What site are you going to that supplies ads in an rss file?

Comment: @Dickie Sorry I didn't understand your question. I would like to save the rss content in a new file without having all that google ads.
@fabrik you think you are funny ?

Comment: @Mikey yep, anyway. Let me enumerate: you didn't provide even a chunk of html so we could see your problem; it looks like you doesn't try (at least) to solve it yourself; unethical; aren't you bannerblind yet?

Comment: @Mikey I was asking what rss feed you were trying to retrieve that had google ads in it. I have found an example at http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot. I have never encountered these before but off the top of my head reading the feed in php then running a short bit of regex would do the trick. I'll need to see several examples to see if this is how they are all implemented otherwise any code I give in an example would only be useful to this specific feed.

Comment: Hi again! I have edited my post with some examples I found and the RSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right lines. Is just your regex needs tweaking.

```
<?php
$feed = file_get_contents('http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot'); //get rss feed
$feed = preg_replace('`&lt;a href="http://feedads\.g\.doubleclick\.net(.*?)&gt;(.*?)&lt;/a&gt;`', '', $feed); //am using ` as my delimiter
var_dump($feed); //do something interesting with your ad-free feed.
```

Comment: Hi there thank you for your answer! It works great! However I have a question, how come it can not work ( or any other preg ) to the RSS i posted?

Comment: I have tested it against the rss feeds you posted and the one I found. What feed are you trying to pull?